# Windows custom scaling break the Winform app look

Tags: c#, winforms, scaling, dpi

I am developing Windows form application using C#. I found that this application is scaled correctly if I used the default scaling offered by Windows 10 (100%, 125%, 150%). But if I used the custom scaling like 110%, 115%, 135%,... the application gone bad. You can see the picture bellow (left is 125% and right is 135%).

[image]

What I have tried so far: enabled dpi awareness, set AutoResizeMode to none/dpi/font, but didn't work.

Is there anyway I can prevent the Windows from breaking my application if the custom scaling is enabled?  I know the Winform is old and also maybe its the Windows problem itself, but any advices will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us a better description of what's wrong/right?  And show some of the _form_.Designer.cs file that shows how the controls are set up?

Comment: The Aspect ration is changing (x size to y size).  See : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/how-do-i-change-aspect-ratio-windows-10/2b61c273-c0d0-461c-ad6c-1be9edaaafec?force_isolation=true

Comment: @Flydog57 thank for your reply, heres the picture of my design: https://imgur.com/a/IYgHThl, you can see it looks exactly like the above left picture.

Comment: @jdweng thanks but i dont think i have this problem, it happens on all windows devices with custom scaling on (at least all my friends who run my program with custom scaling on got the same problem).

Comment: Did you read the link?